# firmata.js - Problems with serialRead()

Tags: javascript, arduino

I'm having trouble making a serial reading of my Serial3 port on an Arduino Mega.
I have a Arduino Mega with this simple program:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Serial print from serial");
  delay(5000);
}
```

This Mega Arduino is connected to another that has "Standard Firmata" loaded. The connection scheme is the following:

*TX0 -> RX3*

*RX0 -> TX3*

My JS file is as follows:

```
import firmata from 'firmata'

const board = new firmata.Board('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201')

board.on('ready', () => {
  const serialPort = board.SERIAL_PORT_IDs.HW_SERIAL3;

  board.serialConfig({
    portId: serialPort,
    baud: 9600
  })

  board.serialRead(serialPort, (data) => {
    console.log(Buffer.from(data).toString('ascii'))
    console.log('Serial port reading')
  })

  board.on('string', (message) => { console.log(message) })

  console.log('Connected board...')
})
```

The connection is established correctly but I do not get any serial reading...
I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StandardFirmataPlus library solves the problem.